# SQL Statement Combine Text Columns Error

Tags: sql

I'm trying to put two strings in my columns VALUE01 and VALUE02 together and then search if a search string exists in this new column. I tried both of the statements below. I get error saying "Invalid column name 'Complete'". What is wrong with these statements? I Use MS SQL Server.

```
SELECT COALESCE(VALUE01, '') + COALESCE(VALUE02, '') AS Complete FROM dbo.Data WHERE Complete LIKE 'Test'"

SELECT (VALUE01 + VALUE02) AS 'Complete' FROM dbo.Data WHERE Complete LIKE 'Test'"
```

Comment: What database brand? Sqlserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use column alias in `WHERE` clause.

Try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(VALUE01, '') + COALESCE(VALUE02, '') AS Complete
FROM dbo.Data
WHERE (COALESCE(VALUE01, '') + COALESCE(VALUE02, '')) LIKE 'Test'"
```

Comment: Perhaps, for performace issues, is preferable: `where VALUE01 like 'Test' or VALUE02 like 'Test'`. You agree?

Comment: @danihp - Good point. I'm not certain to be honest, it might be worth including Client Statistics on SSMS and testing the 2 different queries.

Comment: @danihp: Not necessarily - what if VALUE01 is 'Te' and VALUE02 is 'st'?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Curt and Amit's approach, you could also use a CTE or an inline view, and query on the results - something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT COALESCE(VALUE01, '') + COALESCE(VALUE02, '') AS Complete 
 FROM dbo.Data) ILV
WHERE Complete LIKE 'Test'
```

(Incidentally, using `LIKE` without wildcards produces the same results as if you had used `=` - to check whether the string `Test` appears anywhere in the `Complete` composite column, you should use the condition `WHERE Complete LIKE '%Test%'`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a column alias in the where clause

The following query should do what you need

```
SELECT COALESCE(VALUE01, '') + COALESCE(VALUE02, '') AS Complete FROM dbo.Data WHERE COALESCE(VALUE01, '') + COALESCE(VALUE02, '') LIKE 'Test'
```